# The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9844002. Getting this error

Tags: wcf

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9844002. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You need to add a timeout attribute to the binding, please refer to this link for details:https://forums.asp.net/t/1854170.aspx?The+request+channel+timed+out+while+waiting+for+a+reply+after+00+01+00+Increase+the+timeout+value+passed+to+the+call+to+Request+or+increase+the+SendTimeout+value+on+the+Binding+The+time+allotted+to+this+operation+may+have+been+a+portion+of+a+lon

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, i edited both my App.config and Web.config and nothing.
Then i just tried this:

```
this.clientWCF.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
```

And it works!!!  Problem solved.
Hope this helps you or others in the same predicament.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent advice Jhollman, [service].InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,5,0) increased the timeout wait for service response to 5 minutes